# How can I ensure synchronisation of a collection passed to a method?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have the following method on an internal class which I use to sort a number of collections in a multithreaded app. I want to ensure each of the collections is synchronised while sorting (I already synchronise everywhere else I iterate).

*Note: One of the collections backs an adapter for a ListView.*

```
private void sort(List<...> collection) {
    if (collection != null) {
        Collections.sort(collection, ...);
    }
}
```

The problem is if I wrap `synchronised(collection) { Collections.sort }` the IDE warns me that it's unsafe to synchronise on a method parameter.

I know this is a new reference, but the reference still points to the original collection so is this safe? If not, is there a way to test whether the collection is locked? *(So I can throw an exception if misued)*

Comment: You have no way of knowing if it's wrapped anywhere else, so it's not safe.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean if it's wrapped anywhere else, do you mean I have no way to know if it's already locked? Does that mean there is no way for me to check?

Comment: Just because you're synchronizing in this method doesn't mean some other piece of code can't modify it.  You should wrap your backing list with `List.synchronizedList()` if you want to be safe everywhere. Take a look at the [Wrapper Implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that. I assume I need to also synchronise the sort block because it will iterate through the lists

Comment: If you're in Java 8, I suspect sorting is already covered.

Comment: Thanks, this is an android app, it needs to be Java 7 compatible

Comment: Then I think wrapping in a synchronized block is fine. As long as you're sure of what's being passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question here is how these collections should be accessed.
For example if you want multiple reads and only one writing threads to the collection you should use a wrapper class and ReentrantReadWriteLock:

```
public class ListWrapper {

    private final ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock r = rwl.readLock();
    private final Lock w = rwl.writeLock();    

    public String read() {
        r.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("reading");
            if(theList.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return theList.get(0);
            }
        } finally {
            r.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void write(String data) {
        w.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("Written " + data);
            theList.add(data);
        } finally{
            w.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

The same with a wrapper class which has list inside and does not expose the list directly.

```
public class ListWrapper {    
    private final List<String> obj;     
    public ListWrapper (Object obj) { 
        this.obj = obj; 
    }     

    public List<String> getList() { 
        return obj; 
    } 
}
```

The above class is thread safe because it does not perform any operation on the wrapped objects.
The objects wrapped by the class may or may not be thread safe because after the reference of the wrapped object is returned, multiple threads can operate on the object.

Therefore, whether the wrapped object itself is thread safe or not is determined by how the class of the wrapped object is implemented.

Also you can use

> CopyOnWriteArrayList

where is a thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array.

It is up to the implementation i think.

Comment: Hi, one of my datasets is used to back a listview which I realise now probably changes the whole question. I tried copying to a CopyOnWriteArrayList before sorting then updating afterwards, but of course concurrency issues still occurred because it has to iterate through the list to copy while the UI can continue to make changes

Comment: If you copy your list to CopyOnWriteArrayList i dont think it should do any difference unless only CopyOnWriteArrayList is used in all places. You should use CopyOnWriteArrayList if your application can handle not all viewers to have the latest updates. You can read more in the javadoc. If you use CopyOnWriteArrayList  you can't get concurrency errors because https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I think I'm better with Collections.synchronisedList given the description you linked (I can have a large dataset and during a foreground sync from server writes can be as often as reads)

Comment: Who said `ArrayList.get()` may be called concurrently?

Comment: @shmosel The collection allows multiple concurrent reads but does not tolerate concurrent read and write, thats the point of using the ReentrantReadWriteLock.

Comment: Source, please.

Comment: There is no source the read is always thread safe so if you secure writing with ReentrantReadWriteLock you are thread safe.

Comment: So you don't have a source but we should take your word that it's thread safe (by all definitions) and will remain so in the future. Seems reasonable.

Comment: Ok, I found a [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): *If multiple threads access an `ArrayList` instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.)*

Answer (score -1):

The best advice I can give you is to use a collection in the `java.util.concurrent` [package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and passing that collection along to your methods. These concurrent collections automatically synchronize reads/writes (depending on the collection) no matter where they are modified in code. I recommend you read what each concurrent collection optimizes and pick one based on your application.

The other option is to pass in a synchronized wrapper to your list which you can create like this:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

This basically wraps methods of the collection and makes them synchronized. Passing the returned list along and calling it's member functions ensures they are called serially.

**EDITS:**

Alternatively, I would suggest you create your own Collection (maybe ConcurrentSortableCollection) that synchronizes on itself before sorting. This is useful only if none of the concurrent collections fit what you need and you require special optimization.

You may also make your sort method static synchronized or simply synchronize on the collection passed in before calling your sort(collection) method, which may be easier:

```
synchronized(collection) {
   sort(collection);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the synchronizedList, the problem is it's still down to me to manually synchronise anything that iterates over the collection. Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: shmosel, you don't pass entire objects around in java. You pass a container that points to that object. That is what a "pointer" is by definition. This is why you can't synchronize on a function parameter. It is a different object container, allocated for the scope of the function call (ie on the stack).

Comment: @NickCardoso, Collections.sort() does not iterate over the collection. It dumps the collection into an array, sorts the array, and then resets the array into the collection.  If you want to make sure the nothing gets inserted or deleted in between the 3 steps, then simply add synchronized to your sort method, this way only 1 active thread can sort any collection at any given time. Alternatively I would suggest you create your own Collection (maybe ConcurrentSortableCollection) that synchronizes on itself before sorting. This is useful only if none of the concurrent collections suite you.

Comment: Yes, I know what a pointer is. My earlier statement still stands.